# Open Standard Media (OSM) Player (or similar)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm currently evaluating solutions that will allow me to play a variety of media formats with total control under jquery and the following solution caught my eye:

http://www.mediafront.org/project/osmplayer

**[edit]** - this also looks promising (and may well have answered my own question!! :)):

http://www.protofunc.com/jme/documentation/documentation-api.html

One of my objectives in using any such jquery media player solution would be the ability to capture properties on the media when pausing, stopping, fwd'ing or backw'ding the controls (or subclassed buttons on the page). I know that the above elegantly allows me to control these events via jquery, so far so good. However, I'd additionally like to be able to 'capture' the timeline offset at the point of raising any of these events (i.e. as both a string [format hh:mm:ss:milliseconds] and as an integer offset (i.e. 90000 would represent 1m:30s etc, etc)).

Can the above plugin achieve this goal or is there another solution out there that does implement this functionality as described.??

Looking fwd to a variety of alternatives :)

**[edit]** - may not be possible, but if there are any similar products that support html4, would love to hear about those too (i.e. jquery control with fallback to flash for anything lower than html5) [with feature request as per main question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSM player is at the same time the ugliest and the most complete player I know of.

[Video for everybody](http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/) combined with [jquery.srt.js](http://v2v.cc/~j/jquery.srt/), though, may provide a good starting point for developing your own player.

Also, Opera, Firefox and Safari have no problem rendering `<video>` in a HTML4 page. Some methods of the `<video>` element may be missing here and there but I don't think it's worse than the overall HTML5 situation.

Comment: cheers romainl - i'll take a look at those. i must point out, i'm not really wanting to develop a video player per se - merely find one that will allow me to work with the timeline events for a special project that relies on hitpoints..